# How to set order to arrays when I click next and previous on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, sorting, onclick

I want to create a image viewer where you click next and previous to change the image.
So far the buttons next and previous changes the image. However when I click next then previous, the image doesn't go to the previous image instead it goes to the starting image.

My guess is to create a variable var = newImage and use that variable on function change2() and create a new varirable var= newImage2 and use that on function change().

is that possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS ChangeImage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Change Image</h1>
    <br>
    <div class= "container" align="center">
        <button onclick="change2()">Previous</button>
        <img src="html5.png" style="height: 500px; width: 500px" id="changeimg">
        <button onclick="change()">Next</button>
    </div>

</body>
<script>

    var img=0;
    var imgArr = ["html5.png","css3.png","javascript.png"]

    function change() {
        var image = document.getElementById('changeimg');
        console.log("current image =>", imgArr[img])
        document.getElementById('changeimg').src =imgArr[img];
        if (img== 2) img = 0;
        else
            img++;
    }

    function change2() {
        var c1= 
        document.getElementById('changeimg').src =imgArr[img];
        console.log("current image =>", imgArr[img])
        if (img== 0) img = 2;
        else
            img--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I noticed that you are changing the `img` variable after assigning the image to the element. I think you should switch the order. The way it is now, when you click *Next*, the number advances, but the picture is associated with the previous number. If you then click *Previous*, the number will reduce, but the image will appear to advance.

I've made some other changes for simplicity here:

HTML:

```
<h1 align="center">Change Image</h1>
<br>
<div class= "container" align="center">
    <button onclick="change(event)" name='1'>Previous</button>
    <img src="html5.png" style="width: 500px" id="changeimg">
    <button onclick="change(event)" name='2'>Next</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var currentImg = 0;
const imgArr = ["html5.png","css3.png","javascript.png"]

const change=(event)=>{
    if(event.target.name==='1'){
        currentImg>0?currentImg--:currentImg=2;
    } else if(event.target.name==='2'){
        currentImg<imgArr.length-1?currentImg++:currentImg=0;
    }
    console.log(currentImg);
    document.getElementById('changeimg').src = imgArr[currentImg];
}
```

Please note the use of the 'name' attribute of the  for use in the logic of the change function. This allows me to use only one function for both buttons. I hope this helps.